# Swift: Is not saving NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults values

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I'm trying to save key value in the NSUserDefaults but is not been save. Here is my code:

```
func saveData() {

    let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    userDefaults.setObject("blablabla", forKey:"data")
    userDefaults.synchronize()
}
```

Any of you knows why this data is not been save?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: How do you know it is not saving those values for example that "blablabla"?

Comment: When I try to load the value "userDefaults.dictionaryForKey("data")" is always nil

Comment: `blablabla` is apparently not a dictionary. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Swift 2.x:**

According with Apple sources:

```
public func objectForKey(defaultName: String) -> AnyObject?
```

to retrieve your value you could use:

```
if let value = userDefaults.objectForKey("data")  {
    // do whatever you want with your value
    // P.S. value could be numeric,string,..
}
```

Comment: Apple definitively does not recommend to use `valueForKey` in `NSUserDefaults`. It's `objectForKey`.

Comment: I've in my public apps without problems, where do you read it, it come from sources, can you describe why?

Comment: `valueForKey` is a KVC method with a special behavior. Don't use it unless you really need KVC. Please post a *source* where Apple uses `valueForKey` in `NSUserDefaults`.

Comment: if you check your property accurately before set it you never give a KVC. I never speaking about Apple source where it use valueForKey in NSUserDefaults, I speaking about the availability in apple sources.

Comment: Please link a document where apple does not recommended to use, it will be interesting. I need to know, thank you.

Comment: Apple just never uses nor mentions `valueForKey` in any sample code nor in the `Preferences and Settings Programming Guide`. However in `Key-Value Coding Programming Guide` it's described how to use `valueForKey` reasonably but there is also no reference to `NSUserDefaults`. `valueForKey` is one of the most abused methods because many people don't know what they are doing.

Comment: I think , IMHO the fact that it is not mentioned among the withdrawal methods does not make it a "not recommended" unless it is explicitly documented because it's available , I've never read about it in swift, no warnings, nothing. However thank you for your opinion.

Comment: I've read your updates comment, I agree with objectForKey, it's more correct about valueForKey.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are doing it wrong, try like this:

```
let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
userDefaults.setObject("blablabla", forKey:"data")



let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
if let name = defaults.stringForKey("data") {
    print(name)
}
```

You won't be able to access a string with `dictionaryForKey` because string is not a dictionary value type. Let me know if you need any further help.

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to access a string with 'dictionaryForKey' because a string is not a dictionary value type. You'll need to use:

```
if let savedString = userDefaults.stringForKey("data") {
    print(savedString)
}
```

If you have any further questions feel free to let me know :)